# Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, hibernate-mapping

Here is my Employee.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 
<hibernate-mapping package = "com.demo.hibernate.beans">
   <class name="Employee" table="employee">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

While running hibernate i get the following exception

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.demo.hibernate.beans.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:575)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1593)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1561)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1540)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1434)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1420)
    at com.demo.hibernate.beans.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:514)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:572)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:505)
    ... 8 more
```

What can be the possible reason ?

EDIT : Posting the employee bean

```
public class Employee {
       private int id;
       private String firstName; 
       private String lastName;   
       private int salary;  

       public Employee() {}
       public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
          this.firstName = fname;
          this.lastName = lname;
          this.salary = salary;
       }
       public int getId() {
          return id;
       }
       public void setId( int id ) {
          this.id = id;
       }
       public String getFirstName() {
          return firstName;
       }
       public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
          this.firstName = first_name;
       }
       public String getLastName() {
          return lastName;
       }
       public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
          this.lastName = last_name;
       }
       public int getSalary() {
          return salary;
       }
       public void setSalary( int salary ) {
          this.salary = salary;
       }
    }
```

and the database structure in postgres

```
create table EMPLOYEE (
   id INT NOT NULL   DEFAULT nextval('emp_id_seq'::regclass),
   first_name VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   last_name  VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   salary     INT  default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE SEQUENCE emp_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 10000
  CACHE 1;
```

Comment: Also post your Employee bean and table structure.

Answer (score 3):

Your doctype has a problem. From where you copied? I copied your code and changed docttype. it works.

Use this for Hibernate DOCTYPE 3.0

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```