# Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.HibernateException

Tags: hibernate

Hi I am new to the hibernate framework.when i am running hibernate sample example code it is working fine if internet connection is available.If internet connection is not available then it is not working and is giving error like below:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hb.example.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:20)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1411)
    at com.hb.example.ManageEmployee.main(ManageEmployee.java:17)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
    ... 3 more
```

My example code will be like below:
Employee.java:

```
package com.hb.example;

public class Employee {
       private int id;
       private String firstName; 
       private String lastName;   
       private int salary;  

       public Employee() {}
       public Employee(String fname, String lname, int salary) {
          this.firstName = fname;
          this.lastName = lname;
          this.salary = salary;
       }
       public int getId() {
          return id;
       }
       public void setId( int id ) {
          this.id = id;
       }
       public String getFirstName() {
          return firstName;
       }
       public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
          this.firstName = first_name;
       }
       public String getLastName() {
          return lastName;
       }
       public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
          this.lastName = last_name;
       }
       public int getSalary() {
          return salary;
       }
       public void setSalary( int salary ) {
          this.salary = salary;
       }
    }
```

ManageEmployee.java:

```
package com.hb.example;

import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator; 

import org.hibernate.HibernateException; 
import org.hibernate.Session; 
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ManageEmployee {
   private static SessionFactory factory; 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try{
         factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      }catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }
      ManageEmployee ME = new ManageEmployee();

      /* Add few employee records in database */
      Integer empID1 = ME.addEmployee("Zara", "Ali", 1000);
      Integer empID2 = ME.addEmployee("Daisy", "Das", 5000);
      Integer empID3 = ME.addEmployee("John", "Paul", 10000);

      /* List down all the employees */
      ME.listEmployees();

      /* Update employee's records */
      ME.updateEmployee(empID1, 5000);

      /* Delete an employee from the database */
      ME.deleteEmployee(empID2);

      /* List down new list of the employees */
      ME.listEmployees();
   }
   /* Method to CREATE an employee in the database */
   public Integer addEmployee(String fname, String lname, int salary){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      Integer employeeID = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
         employeeID = (Integer) session.save(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
      return employeeID;
   }
   /* Method to  READ all the employees */
   public void listEmployees( ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         List employees = session.createQuery("FROM Employee").list(); 
         for (Iterator iterator = 
                           employees.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            Employee employee = (Employee) iterator.next(); 
            System.out.print("First Name: " + employee.getFirstName()); 
            System.out.print("  Last Name: " + employee.getLastName()); 
            System.out.println("  Salary: " + employee.getSalary()); 
         }
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
   /* Method to UPDATE salary for an employee */
   public void updateEmployee(Integer EmployeeID, int salary ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = 
                    (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         employee.setSalary( salary );
         session.update(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
   /* Method to DELETE an employee from the records */
   public void deleteEmployee(Integer EmployeeID){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Employee employee = 
                   (Employee)session.get(Employee.class, EmployeeID); 
         session.delete(employee); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
   }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

<----->

<--  --->

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      root
   </property>

   <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Employee.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Here i done the modification but it is not working

<--- 
     --->

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="com.hb.example.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So can any one help please for me.

Comment: I have answered the similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32731952/458701

Answer (score 1):

See the 3rd & 4th lines in your hibernate configuration & mapping file respectively.

The document for DTD says:

> Hibernate will not load the DTD file from the web, but first look it
>   up from the classpath of the application. The DTD file is included in
>   hibernate-core.jar (it is also included in the hibernate3.jar, if
>   using the distribution bundle).

You're getting this exception in absence of Internet because MOSTLY it tries to load DTD files for both hibernate configuration & mapping files, from Internet, in your application.

When your application is started & the first time it accesses hibernate configuration file it tries to parse the configuration file using its DTD file, which is downloaded from **www.hibernate.org**.

For more on Hiberate DTD, please have a look at these:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/73208-how-to-configure-hibernate-cfg-xml-to-work-offline

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-mapping

**UPDATE :-**

How to work with Hibernate Offline?

For Hibernate Configuration file:

1. Change your DTD file declaration to

   `<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">`
2. Download hibernate configuration DTD file from : http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd & set it to your classpath.

For hibernate mapping files:

1. Change your DTD file declaration to

   `<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">`
2. Download hibernate configuration DTD file from : http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd & set it to your classpath.

This should work properly.

Comment: I think solution is provided in the 1st link only. Have you gone through it?

Comment: Yes.I gone through the link.When i replace 2 & 3rd lines with the code  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"> i am getting new error  i.e mapping exception can u please help

Comment: Now i have posted modified code just see and guide mw where i have done my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I see one similar question today and I answered. Seems like your hbm file also has DOCTYPE mismatch. Check it once. It should work.

[Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource Employee.hbm.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506853/failed-to-create-sessionfactory-object-org-hibernate-invalidmappingexception-co/19900161#19900161)

Use below doctype:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  I don't know, how this text missed in my answer.

Comment: If internet is present my example is working if internet is not present then only it is raising error

Answer (score 0):

There may be the case that your ManageEmployee.java is not able to populate the configuration(hibernate.cfg.xml) file.You can add the below piece of code to populate the configuration file.

```
Configuration cfg=new Configuration();  //create Configuration object first

cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");//populates the data of the configuration file  
factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory(); //then u can create session factory object and u can begin your transaction
```

The following worked for me hope it work for you also :)