# Hibernate tutorial. Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, database-connection

I want to learn how Hibernate works, so found [this tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-create-hibernate-application-in-eclipse-ide). But i get this error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
at mypackage.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:14)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
... 2 more
```

I found out, that many people have the same issue with the same tutorial. For example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506853/failed-to-create-sessionfactory-object-org-hibernate-invalidmappingexception-co/19900161#19900161), or [another link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/593063/ORM/databases/hibernate-programme).

Another issue is, that it takes far to long to show the error after starting the programm(40 sek).

Here is my main class:

```
package mypackage;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class StoreData {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // creating configuration object
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");// populates the data of the

        // configuration file

        // creating seession factory object
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

        // creating session object
        Session session = factory.openSession();

        // creating transaction object
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setId(115);
        e1.setFirstName("Elvis");
        e1.setLastName("Presley");

        session.persist(e1);// persisting the object

        transaction.commit();// transaction is committed
        session.close();

        System.out.println("successfully saved");
    }catch (HibernateException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Hibernate configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=hibernatetutorial;</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Employee xml:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">  

 <hibernate-mapping>  
  <class name="mypackage.Employee" table="emp1000">  
    <id name="id">  
     <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
    </id>  

    <property name="firstName"></property>  
    <property name="lastName"></property>  

  </class>  

 </hibernate-mapping>
```

and Employee.java:

```
package mypackage;

public class Employee {

private int id;
private String firstName; 
private String lastName;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

}
```

And this are my jars and all files.

[image: Package Explorer]

Someone knows what is the issue here?

Comment: Your hibernate.cfg.xml seems to be incomplete. Must be more like [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig).

Comment: can someone please add bounty on this question, I don't have enough points, but I really need an answer.

Comment: Why don't you try one of the million other hibernate tutorials?

Comment: Most of other tutorials are for advanced programmers, or with Maven, which I am not supposed to use. This one is simple and I understand how it works, but I need it to function so I can go on, and implement Spring framework to it.

Answer (score 1):

in your Hibernate configuration file, mapping is commented, and

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create_drop</property>
```

is supposed to be update, not create_drop

Comment: just try some other tutorials, and then go back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error. In my case with another hibernate maven [tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html), I just forgot to run the service like this:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.hsqldb.Server" -Dexec.args="-database.0 file:target/data/tutorial"
```